# Noise-canceling headphones

Tags: headphones

Note: I've seen [this](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/286/headphones-for-filtering-out-noise-in-an-open-space-office) thread but my expectations are a little bit more specific.

I'd like to ask you about headphones which may filter the noise a way better than stoppers (ear plugs):

- highly effective noise-canceling
- comfy earpads (very important)
- no integrated microphone
- full-size (fully cover the ear)
- audio quality is not that important
- cheaper than $350

Considered as a plus:

- a possibility to swivel the earpads vertically and laterally
- detachable headphone cord (being able to cancel the noise without the audio)
- rechargeable

Comment: By those last two points, I'm assuming you mean that _wireless connectivity_ is a plus?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I meant a possibility to cancel the noise without an audio. Rechargeable is in terms of an active noise reduction.

Comment: There are headphones, used on shooting ranges to protect ears from the sound of shooting. They're probably the most effective for canceling noise. But no music, alas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, I doubt any active noise reduction (ANR) is going to beat out good passive noise reduction (PNR) in-ear plugs ("stoppers").  ANR headphones will be more comfortable than PNR and may provide better overall noise reduction for part of the audio spectrum, but not for all of it.  If you really need a replacement for a good set of in-ear plugs, you might end up disappointed.

My recommendation are Bose headphones.  I've owned a few of their ANR products* and have used a few competitor products, though not at the consumer level.

I can recommend the [Bose QC15 headphones](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0054JJ0QW) but they are discontinued (but still available) and the current model is the [QC25 headphone](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00M1NEUKK).  They have

- great ANR qualities
- comfortable to wear all day
- no microphone
- are the around-the-ear variant of the headphones that completely cover the ear
- headphone audio is great
- $299
- ear pads rotate up-down and side-to-side (to the point they can lay flat)
- the headphone cord is detachable so they can be *just* noise cancelling with no audio

They are not rechargeable, but (the QC15) takes a single AAA battery and you can use rechargeable in it.

* I have extensive experience with the Bose QC2, Bose QC15, Bose X, Lightspeed Sierra, and Lightspeed Zulu.  The first two are the same headsets in subsequent produce cycles and the QC25 is the next iteration of those headphones.  I don't have direct experience with the QC25, but I don't have any reason to doubt it.  I can attest to the QC15 being a great product.  The last 3 headsets listed are aviation ANR headsets which I have used in high-noise environments (slow twin propeller and fast twin turbojet airplanes).  I'd be happy wearing the QC15 in those environments and they perform well against those $500-$1000 aviation headsets.

Comment: +1 for the Bose QC - I have used them for many, many long haul flights (picked mine up in 2005 or so and still going strong) and I just use a couple of AAA rechargeables - sound quality is pretty good too.